# Hydraulics: Pulling Up Instead of Down

Tags: pressure

Let $P_1$ be the pressure on the left and $P_2$ be the pressure on the right. We know that $P_1=P_2\implies \frac{F_1}{\pi r_1^2}=\frac{F_2}{\pi r_2^2}$.

> Now, let's say we apply $F_1$ upward as opposed to downward. Water would rise into the tube on the left. Would this imply $P_1=P_2$ again? So, $\frac{F_1}{\pi r_1^2}=\frac{F_2}{\pi r_2^2}\implies F_2=\frac{r_2^2F_1}{r_1^2}$. So, increasing $F_1$ increases $F_2$, increasing $r_2$ increases $F_2$, and decreasing $r_1$ increases $F_2$.

> Or would there be a limitation on the amount of force $F_2$ could have as lifting upward on $F_1$  creates a vacuum? Would this somehow relate to atmospheric pressure?

[image]

Comment: Cavitation would be a limit. But see this - [How Trees Bend the Laws of Physics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BickMFHAZR0)

Comment: @mmesser314 So, are you saying that $F_2=\frac{r_2^2F_1}{r_1^2}$ holds true up until the $P_1\leq 1 \text{ atm}$. After $P_1 >1 \text{ atm}$, it would not be able to hold more water.

Comment: If you pull upward hard enough on both ends, the fluid will cavitate. I don't know how much force that would require. If the tension force in the fluid is less than enough to cause cavitation, pulling up on one end causes a downward force on the other with $F_2=\frac{r_2^2}{r_1^2}F_1$

Comment: @mmesser314, the only force that opposes cavitation is the force due to atmospheric pressure. If the whole experiment is performed in vacuum, then no force at all would be needed to cavitate. In fact, you would have to apply some downward force to both pistons to stop the fluid from boiling.

Comment: @SolomonSlow - You wouldn't think so, but liquids actually can support negative pressures. The equivalent of tension in a solid. Molecules in a liquid do attract each other. See the link on trees above.